# I trying integrate mollie with gatsby but I have issue

Tags: reactjs, frontend, gatsby, payment, mollie

I integrate mollie script in gatsby layout

class Layout extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props)
}

```
componentDidMount() {
}

componentDidUpdate() {
}

render() {

    return (

        <>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <Header/>
                    {this.props.children}
                </Provider>
            </BrowserRouter>
            <Script src="https://js.mollie.com/v1/mollie.js"/>
        </>
    )
}
```

}

I integrate mollie script in gatsby layout
I integrate mollie script in gatsby layout
I integrate mollie script in gatsby layout

const PaymentPage = () => {
const [paymentUrl, setPaymentUrl] = useState('');

```
const createPayment = async () => {
    if (typeof window.Mollie !== 'undefined') {
        try {
            const mollie = window.Mollie({
                apiKey: 'test_96m24F3ncSJyj7nFpmKP5pjSn3RzrD',
            });

            const payment = await mollie.payments.create({
                amount: {
                    currency: 'EUR',
                    value: '10.00',
                },
                description: 'Sample Payment',
                redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/payment-success',
                method: 'ideal', // Payment method (change as needed)
            });

            setPaymentUrl(payment._links.checkout.href);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error creating payment:', error);
        }
    }
};

return (
    <div>
        <h1>Gatsby Mollie Integration Example</h1>
        <button onClick={createPayment}>Create Payment</button>
        {paymentUrl && (
            <div>
                <p>Click the button below to complete your payment:</p>
                <a href={paymentUrl} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                    Complete Payment
                </a>
            </div>
        )}
    </div>
);
```

};

**My error :
Error creating payment: TypeError: t.startsWith is not a function at new t (mollie.js:1:92514)